# How can you force Unity to Create a new instance?

Tags: c#, wcf, design-patterns, dependency-injection, unity-container

Using Unity Application block how can you force the Unity configuration to create a new instance of an object when we call the `UnityContainer.Resolve<T>()`  method in WCF context?

Comment: Which lifetime manager you are using? also, you want to dispose un-managed object?

Comment: I have not configured a lifetime manager, I need to dispose my repository objects

Comment: why do you know that your repository object is not disposed?

Comment: If I manually update the database it is not reflected in Entity Framework, also I have included a line in the Dispose method to log the fact he method is called in a text file and the log is not being created

Comment: I got it, well, Unity does not support to call Dispose for you,it just release the reference, and let GC to collect.  Most of IoCs, you need to manually do disposing

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[Lifetime Manager](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff660872%28v=pandp.20%29.aspx) in `Unity` is all what you need. By default, Unity use `TransientLifetimeManager`:

> TransientLifetimeManager. For this lifetime manager Unity creates and returns a new instance of the requested type for each call to the Resolve or ResolveAll method. This lifetime manager is used by default for all types registered using the RegisterType, method unless you specify a different lifetime manager.

If you need to use another lifetime manager, just specify in `Register` method:

```
var container = new UnityContainer();
container.RegisterType<IMyType, MyType>(new PerResolveLifetimeManager());
```

Answer (score 2):

Using `RegisterType` without `a LifetimeManager` should inject a new instance of the type every time it is injected

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff660923%28v=pandp.20%29):

> If you do not specify a value for the lifetime, the type is registered
>   for  a transient lifetime, which means that a new instance will be
>   created on each  call to Resolve

Comment: This is working, but now when I implement this in my WCF app it is not disposing any objects, any ideas?

Comment: @AndyClark clark - We are also using Unity 2.1.505, EF 4.3.1 with a repository pattern, under a WCF service layer, also with config setup. One difference could be that we are using a WCF service behaviour to bootstrap? http://rafatolotti.wordpress.com/2010/09/12/wcf-unity-app-block/.