# UnitOfWork + Repository Pattern

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5, unity-container, repository-pattern, unit-of-work

I have a very strange situation. I have a UOW Repository pattern. I have domain layer which houses my entities, A Data Access layer which contains the dbcontext (UnitofWork) and repositories for different entities. I have an application layer where i have services which i call for reading and writing data. Architecture contains basically this with some DTOs to help consistency in data. I have a UI layer with MVC5 where i have injected all the dependencies through Unity and it works great if i instantiate each service from a controller constructer.

I have quiet a few services such as GlobalAppSvc (Implemented from IGlobalAppSvc), SystemSettingAppSvc (ISystemSettingAppSvc) etc etc. To make life easier I've created a class called ApplicationManager like this.

```
 public class ApplicationManager
{
    public ApplicationManager(ISystemSettingAppSvc systemSettingAppSvc, IBalanceAppSvc balanceAppSvc, IGlobalAppSvc globalAppSvc, IProfileAppSvc profileAppSvc)
    {
        SystemSettingAppSvc = systemSettingAppSvc;
        BalanceAppSvc = balanceAppSvc;
        GlobalAppSvc = globalAppSvc;
        ProfileAppSvc = profileAppSvc;
    }
    public ISystemSettingAppSvc SystemSettingAppSvc { get; set; }
    public IBalanceAppSvc BalanceAppSvc { get; set; }
    public IGlobalAppSvc GlobalAppSvc { get; set; }
    public IProfileAppSvc ProfileAppSvc { get; set; }
}
```

In my Unity i have Registered all the Services and Repositories along with the Unit of Work

```
container.RegisterType<IUnitOfWork, WUnitOfWork>(new PerResolveLifetimeManager(), new InjectionConstructor());
container.RegisterType<IWUnitOfWork, WUnitOfWork>(new PerResolveLifetimeManager(), new InjectionConstructor());
```

I have created a `BaseController` by extending `Controller` so that i don't have to resolve Application manager in every controller i write. In base controller i am resolving this `ApplicationManager` as

```
public class BaseController : Controller
{
    // GET: Base
    public ApplicationManager ApplicationManager
    {
        get;
        private set;
    }

    public BaseController()
    {

        ApplicationManager = UnityConfig.Container
            .Resolve<ApplicationManager>(); 
    }
}
```

I can then go in any controller and extend the controller with this `BaseController` and i have access to `ApplicationManager.GlobalAppSvc.Methods()...`

My problem is that whenever there is a data modification such as lets say there is an action which executes to deduct the balance and save changes for a particular user. When i request the user's balance again it is still showing unchanged balance however the balance in Database is deducted but the service is not fetching the updated data. What am i doing wrong?

Comment: I wonder if you are running into an issue where the data is being kept in-memory because of your PerResolveLifetimeManager.  Can you try it with TransientLifetimeManager and see if that resolves your issue?

Comment: Hi, I've tried this and this doesn't work either. Is there something wrong with resolving application manager the way i did?

Comment: Can't really answer that given that I don't know anything about the implementations of the interfaces that are used within it?  If they are managing state internally, then it could very well be your issue.  My guess without seeing all the code is that your container lifetime is causing data to be held in-memory longer than you are expecting it to.   This was the reason I wondered if transient might help.  Without being able to see all the code, it's hard to say what is happening.   What is the difference between IUnitOfWork and IWUnitOfWork?

Comment: Hi, IWUnitOfWork is an extended version of IUnitofWork to handle exceptions to specific. Also one more thing I've noticed is that if i make some changes to the data in Database manually from SQL Server Management Studio and when i fetch that row it is still showing old data.  **_ public interface IWUnitOfWork : IUnitOfWork_**

Comment: You'd have to show code from one of those calls for me to be able to help more.

Comment: Sure tell me which one do you need i will show the code here or if you have any live chat ID we can try and communicate there. Once we solve the issue we can come back here and mark the answer.

Comment: Eliminate the update/read scenario and show the one that works off this reply "if i make some changes to the data in Database manually from SQL Server Management Studio and when i fetch that row it is still showing old data".   If you are doing this, it clearly isn't hitting the database on the read.

Comment: I've tried to add the code here but it didn't let me so here is a paste bin 
https://pastebin.com/idTNxE1D

Comment: This helps...but have some questions based on what's there.  How is your unitofwork.Balances list populated?   I don't see that part in the code you pasted in.  Based on your design, I would wager that balances is loaded only once and you are only applying your Where logic to that data that was loaded versus requerying the database when GetByUserId is called.

Comment: Since it is a generic repository pattern i have a **Repository** which takes <TEntity> as another class (Entity) and provides the generic get by id, getall kind of methods...As BalanceRepository inherits the Repository<Balance> it automatically gets those method available for me to use.  Here is another Pastebin for actual DB Context implementation and also the generic repository implementation. 

https://pastebin.com/MScaK3uu

Comment: I got ya....didn't realize you were using EF.   I don't see anything in the Repo class that would be causing your issue, which leads me back to my original thought about Unity and the life cycle of your unit of work.  That thought lead me to this SO Q/A:   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12057299/how-can-you-force-unity-to-create-a-new-instance.  The 4th comment states exactly what you said about manually updating the database and the changes not being reflected in EF.  When you tried the transient version did you also try the manual update too?  Or did you only try that in the live trial?

Comment: I've finally got it to work by resolving my  ApplicationManager=UnityConfig.Container.Resolve<ApplicationManager>();  and registering types as   container.RegisterType<IBalanceAppSvc, BalanceAppSvc>(new PerResolveLifetimeManager()); and it worked. Now changes made in database are reflecting immediately. Any updates made through the code also working fine. Thank you so much for your help @user1011627 you've been really really helpful.

Comment: Cool....glad you got it working.

Comment: Thank you so much. Is there anyway i can mark your reply as an answer. I think that's the least i can do to thank you.

Comment: No, but how about I just add your fix as an answer and you can accept that.   :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the solution is to ensure the BalanceAppSvc needs to be registered with Unity as such:

```
ApplicationManager=UnityConfig.Container.Resolve<ApplicationManager>(); and registering types as container.RegisterType<IBalanceAppSvc, BalanceAppSvc>(new PerResolveLifetimeManager());
```